# Type assertion in new statement (typescript)?

Tags: typescript

code:

```
new Klass<number>()
```

What does `<number>` part mean? Is it the type of the first constructor parameter?

Comment: *What* first constructor parameter?

Comment: It's a generic type argument !

Answer (score 5):

It's a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type argument. Generics allow you to leave certain type bindings open when designing a class or function, to be defined them later. For example `Klass` could be defined like this:

```
class Klass<T> {
   data: T;
}
```

In this case, the class member `data` is of generic type `T` which is an open type within the class. And used like this:

```
const instance = new Klass<number>();
instance.data = 123;   // valid;
instance.data = "123"; // error
```

Because `instance` is of type `Klass<number>`, the type parameter `T` is bound to the type argument `number`, and therefore the type of `instance.data` is `number`.